# Design pattern for entities with lot of inter-dependent events

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

So I'm writing a small note taking application. Here are the various entities and the events via which they've to update their state / view.

```
| Notebook              | Notes            | Status bar            |
|-----------------------|------------------|-----------------------|
| Note added            | Notebook changed | Notebook changed      |
| Note deleted          | Notebook deleted | Notebook deleted      |
| Note completed        | Notebook added   | Date changed          |
| Hours added / changed | Date changed     | Note added            |
| Date changed          |                  | Note deleted          |
|                       |                  | Note completed        |
|                       |                  | Hours added / changed |
|                       |                  | Date changed          |
```

I'm planning to use a variation of the observer pattern to handle the events between the various entities.

```
                                                     +---------------+
+--------------+                                     |               |
|              |                                     |   Notebook    |
|    Notes     |                                     |               |
|              |                                     +-------+-------+
+--------------+                                             |
               |              +--------------+               |
               |              |              |               |
               +-------------->  Mediator    <---------------+
                              |              |
                              +-------^------+
                                      |
                                      |
     +----------------+               |
     |                |               |
     |  Status bar    +---------------+
     |                |
     +----------------+
```

The mediator will receive all the events and then pass them onto the appropriate subscribers for that event.

Lets take an example - User updates a note and marks it completed, in which case the following has to be done,

1. Number of completed notes in the notebook should change.
2. Number of completed notes in the status bar should change.

Lets take the above example and look at some code that demonstrates what I'm trying to do -

### Mediator

```
'use strict';

class Mediator {
  constructor () {
    this._list = {};
  }

  subscribe (eventName, cb) {
    if (!this._list[eventName]) {
      this._list[eventName] = [];
    }

    this._list[eventName].push(cb);
  };

  trigger (eventName, data) {
    let subscribers = this._list[eventName] || [];
    for (let i = 0, len = subscribers.length; i < len; ++i) {
      let currSubscriber = subscribers[i];
      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        currSubscriber.apply(null, data);
      } else {
        currSubscriber(data);
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Mediator;
```

### Notebook

```
this.mediator.subscribe('evt.note.completed', this.noteCompleted);
```

### Statusbar

```
this.mediator.subscribe('evt.note.completed', this.noteCompleted);
```

### Note

```
this.mediator.trigger('evt.note.completed', note);
```

Is this a variation of the observer pattern? Is there a better pattern than this to handle my use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is actually somewhat re-inventing the [flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview.html).

In the flux architecture, `Notes`, `Notebook`, and `Statusbar` are View-Controllers (acting as a `Controller` in this step) that receive events (or `Actions`) from the user or web APIs, propagate them to the `Mediator`, which in flux is called the `Dispatcher`. Then that dispatches the events to the `Stores` that are subscribed (which is like a `Model` in MVC architecture). The `Stores` update their `state` accordingly and the View-Controllers bound to the `Stores` are then re-rendered (acting as a `View`). In updating their view, they may or may not dispatch another `Action` that then goes to the `Dispatcher` again cyclically. In [React](https://github.com/facebook/react), which is an implementation of the flux architecture, View-Controllers are implemented as Components.

Below is a figure illustrating the flow described above:

[image]